# What is the error in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I have the below jQuery code, but it does not work at all.

Firebug says there is a `)` missing, but where?

```
$.get(url: 'example.html', function(data) {
        var $page = $(data);
        $page.filter('script').add($page.find('script')).each(function(){
            $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
        });
        $('#form').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: You have too many `}`. A `)` is expected after the first one.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get(url: 'example.html',...
```

should be

```
$.get('example.html',...
```

and you have one `}` too much at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('example.html', function(data) {
        var $page = $(data);
        $page.filter('script').add($page.find('script')).each(function(){
            $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
        });
        $('#form').html(data);
    } // <---- this thing is not needed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a extra `}` and `url: 'example.html'` that part should not contain `url:`

```
$.get(/*url: This part is removed*/'example.html', function(data) {
    var $page = $(data);
    $page.filter('script').add($page.find('script')).each(function(){
        $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
    });
    $('#form').html(data);
    //} This one has also been removed
});
```